# Laravel, cannot delete database row

Tags: database, laravel

So, I have a single page for every database row on my website. When I look at this single page I have created a button to delete the specific row from the database. For this case, it's id 17.

**I'm using Laravel 5.4**

How do I do this? I get this error: `NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:`

My routes:

```
Route::get('/deleteSite{id}', 'ScanController@delete');
```

Controller:

```
public function delete($id) {

        $scan = Scan::find($id);
        $scan->delete();

        return redirect('home');

    }
```

My url: `http://seo.website.nl/deleteSite/17?`(17 is the id that i want to delete, why is the question mark here?)

Button:

```
 <form method="GET" action="/deleteSite/{{$scan->id}}"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></form>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your routes you forgot to add `/` between `deleteSite` and `{id}`.

Change it to this:

```
Route::get('/deleteSite/{id}', 'ScanController@delete');
```

Comment: Omg... Hours searching for the problem and it's a typo.... Thanks dud! Appreciate ya!

Answer (score 0):

Your route is missing a slash:

```
Route::get('/deleteSite{id}', 'ScanController@delete');
                      ^
```

change it to

```
Route::get('/deleteSite/{id}', 'ScanController@delete');
                       ^
```

Also your code is against restfull pattern. Search about it.